# Is there a way to Segment all users who come in with a certain query string?

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics

I have partners sending me traffic to example.com/?refcode=PARTNER -- I want to be able to segment these users and see how they interact with my site. Is this something I can setup via the interface or do I need to use some sort of trackEvents() function to push this info based on me fetching this data via server side via PHP?

Comment: You could create an advanced segment that looks for that particular query parameter in your page paths.